# How to query account balance use EOS api?

Tags: cleos, api

How to query the balance of an account using EOS api? Is is possible to query account balance with public key or account name?

Answer (score 2):

You can check balance using account name.
Check out [`get_currency_balance` endpoint](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_currency_balance)

Balances are specific to a smart contract.
Use `eosio.token` as `code` parameter for a system smart contract polling.
You can left `symbol` parameter empty to poll all the tokens.

Also you can get account names from public key using [`get_key_accounts` endpoint](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_key_accounts-1)